# How to format the Gridview column which has DateTime value at runTime

Tags: c#, gridview, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am using this code to bind the data to the datagrid. I am creating a Datagrid at runtime and don't want to create the Gridview in design time. And I cannot use the `RowDataBound` event. Is there any means by which we can format the column such that I will get only date not the time.

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

There is one column in Gridview named as `MyDate` which is showing the data as `12/12/2010 with Time`. I wanted to remove the time.

I wanted to use something like `DataFormatString="{0:d/M/yyyy}"`.

Comment: What is the type of MyDate

Comment: Type of MyDate is Date/Time [datasource is MSAccess]

Comment: dipesh try below code i post it will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry but that doesnt solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data type of `Mydate` to date instead of `datetime`, or use `Split()` to split the date and time. Store the date in one string and time in another string and then you can bind the grid with the string containing the date.

Comment: as the datasource of the Gridview is MSAccess and their i have specified as DateTime, so i guess i cannot change that.Also how can i split the value of Column- can you advise

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();
    dr["MyDate"]=DateTime.Now.Date;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: if use the above code , i am getting  Column data as "9/30/2013  12:00:00 AM"